# Замена в String.format '.' на ','

Tags: java, строки, format

Пишу (русским языком) в формате разделитель "."(точка), в выводе "," (запятая).

```
Double d = -835.2221557866648;
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("####.######");
System.out.println(  myFormatter.format(d) );
System.out.println( String.format("%.6f", d) );
```

output

```
-835,222156
-835,222156
```

P.S. Есть предположение, что выставленно в системе разделитель ",". Если это действительно влияет, то как ему задать "ногами" использовать разделитель "."(точку)?

Comment: сменить локаль, года два назад был вопрос на эту тему

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5054217/2908793

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%.6f", d);
```

Comment: Спасибо, Помогло!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, отметьте ответ как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)